# How to sort data using different keys using spinner android

Tags: android, sorting, spinner

This is my code for sorting using my tag which is a string

```
Collections.sort(List, new Comparator<Livestock>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Livestock livestock, Livestock right) {
                    return livestock.getTag().compareTo(right.getTag());
                }
            });
```

and this one's for by names

```
Collections.sort(List, new Comparator<Livestock>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Livestock livestock, Livestock right) {
                    return livestock.getName().compareTo(right.getName());
                }
            });
```

I have a spinner that chooses whether to sort by name or by tag but I don't know how to implement it any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done something similar, where the action to change the order of the spinner comes from a `Floating Action Button`. I simply call a method to sort (where I've extracted the `Comparator` to a separate class) and then `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the `Adapter`:

```
public void sortDate(boolean firstToLast) {
    if (firstToLast) {
        sortOrder = "dateFirstSeen";
        Collections.sort(speciesList, new AscendingDateComparator());
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else {
        sortOrder = "dateLastSeen";
        Collections.sort(speciesList, new DescendingDateComparator());
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Works a treat...

Answer (score 0):

If the user either clicks on the spinner-item or presses an accept button you just look which one is selected:

```
spinnerName.getSelectedItem();
```

And then test with an if clause or an switch which item is selected and than execute any of the sorting Algorithms.